# Десериализация xml

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть форма1 с кнопкой, которая вызывает форму2. На форме2 есть два чекбокса и кнопка "Сохранить". Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно выполнить десериализацию (чтение настроек из файла xml) для значений checkBox-ов на второй форме? Код ниже работает правильно только для записи настроек в файл xml.

Класс Props:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace test
{
    public class PropsFields
    {
        public String XMLFileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "settings.xml");
        public Boolean BoolValue1 = true;
        public Boolean BoolValue2 = true;
    }

    public class Props
    {
        public PropsFields Fields;

        public Props()
        {
            Fields = new PropsFields();
        }

        public void WriteXml()
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PropsFields));
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Fields.XMLFileName);
            ser.Serialize(writer, Fields);
            writer.Close();
        }

        public void ReadXml()
        {
            if (File.Exists(Fields.XMLFileName))
            {
                XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PropsFields));
                TextReader reader = new StreamReader(Fields.XMLFileName);
                Fields = ser.Deserialize(reader) as PropsFields;
                reader.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                //можно написать вывод сообщения если файла не существует
            }
        }
    }

}
```

В первой форме:

```
    namespace test
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {

        Props props = new Props();

                //чтение настроек:
        private void readSetting()
        {
            props.ReadXml();
            Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
            frm2.checkBox1.Checked = props.Fields.BoolValue1;
            frm2.checkBox2.Checked = props.Fields.BoolValue2;
            frm2.Close();
            frm2.Dispose();
        }

 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            readSetting();
}
        private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
            if (frm2.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                props.Fields.BoolValue1 = frm2.checkBox1.Checked;
                props.Fields.BoolValue2 = frm2.checkBox2.Checked;

                props.WriteXml();
            }
            frm2.Close();
            frm2.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: что конкретно не работает? Ошибку выдает? Файл не находит? Поля не отмечает? Какая проблема то?

Comment: Проблема, что в форму2 (в ней задаются свойства checked  для чекбоксов) не считываются свойства BoolValue1 и BoolValue2. Т.е. при запуске формы1(главной формы) не считываются свойства из файла xml в форму2. Можно ли вообще при запуске программы прочитать данные из xml во вторую (не главную) форму?

Comment: Пробовали дебажить? Почему не считываются? Файла нет или путь к файлу неверный или ошибка какая или что?

Comment: @olga Вы можете при запуске программы прочитать данные из xml и передать их в конструктор второй формы во время ее вызова. Или же сделать публичное статичное поле к которому будете обращаться с других форм.

Answer (score -1):

При запуске программы вызывайте Settings.Load(), после чего обращайтесь к полям Settings.Current.TestField1

```
public class Settings
{
    private static Settings _Current;

    private Settings() { }

    public static void SetDefault()
    {
        _Current = new Settings();
    }

    public static Settings Current
    {
        get {
            if (_Current == null)
                _Current = new Settings();
            return _Current;
        }
    }

    public static void Load()
    {
        if (File.Exists(_SettingsFileName))
        {
            Stream file = File.Open(_SettingsFileName, FileMode.Open);
            XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
            _Current = (Settings)formatter.Deserialize(file);
            file.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            SetDefault();
            Save();
        }
    }

    public static void Save()
    {
        Stream file = File.Open(_SettingsFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
        formatter.Serialize(file, Current);
        file.Close();
    }

    public static readonly string CurrentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

    private static string _SettingsFileName = Path.Combine(CurrentDirectory, "Settings.xml");

    public int TestField1 = 32300;
    public string TestField2 = "Hello world";
```

}

Comment: Поставил минус, так как 1) Ваш код недооформлен. 2) Непонятно, какую проблему решает 3) Добавляет неверно реализованный синглтон (с точки зрения многопоточности), который непонятно для чего вообще там нужен 4) зачем делать Save в Load'e?